# Workaround for accessing type parameters in class from a static function in dart

Tags: generics, dart, static, static-methods

I'm trying to create a wrapper class which methods in it need to be static and the class should be generic
so, I write:

```
class Resource<T> {
     Resource({@required this.status, this.data, this.message});

     String message;
     Status status;
     T data;

     static Resource<T> success(T data) =>
        Resource(status: Status.SUCCESS, data: data);

     static Resource<T> error(String msg, T data) =>
        Resource(status: Status.ERROR, data: data, message: msg);

     static Resource<T> loading(T data) =>
        Resource(status: Status.LOADING, data: data)
}
```

so, I can use it like this:

```
Resource<T> handleSuccess(data: T) {
    return Resource.success(data)
}
```

but, I got an error `static members can't reference type parameters of the class`

Is there any workaround to implement this behavior?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two options. Either make the static methods generic:

```dart
     static Resource<T> success<T>(T data) =>
        Resource(status: Status.SUCCESS, data: data);

     static Resource<T> error<T>(String msg, T data) =>
        Resource(status: Status.ERROR, data: data, message: msg);

     static Resource<T> loading<T>(T data) =>
        Resource(status: Status.LOADING, data: data);
```

or turn them intro factory constructors:

```dart
     factory Resource.success(T data) =>
        Resource(status: Status.SUCCESS, data: data);

     factory Resource.error(String msg, T data) =>
        Resource(status: Status.ERROR, data: data, message: msg);

     factory Resource.loading(T data) =>
        Resource(status: Status.LOADING, data: data)
```

Either should work. The main difference is where you put the type argument if you want to provide it explicitly. Either:

```dart
  Resource.data<int>(42)  // Static method
```

or

```dart
  Resource<int>.data(42);  // factory.
```

Comment: The second solution is missing that the methods should be named constructor also because I got an error `The default constructor is already defined`.

Comment: Good catch, my bad.